# Add a node inside a node tree - XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm actually performing a transformation with XSL, and I need to create a template that manage to add a node inside a node tree and return all this node tree with the new node.

In my exemple, I would like to add the node `<node3>HIJ</node3>` after `</node2>`, it's working at some point but i'm loosing the upper node.

The node tree :

```
<xsl:variable name="A">
  <node>
    <node1>ABC</node1>
    <node2>DEF</node2>
    <node4>KLM</node4>
  </node>
</xsl:variable>
```

The call of the template

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$A" mode="copy">
  <xsl:with-param name="ValueOfTheNode" select="'HIJ"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

My template that actually doesn't work

```
<xsl:template match="node()/*" mode="copy">
    <xsl:param name="ValueOfTheNode"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="./name() = 'node2'">
        <node3>
            <xsl:value-of select="$ValueOfTheNode"/>
        </node3>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Current result :

```
<node1>ABC</node1>
<node2>DEF</node2>
<node3>HIJ</node3>
<node4>KLM</node4>
```

Expected result

```
<node>
    <node1>ABC</node1>
    <node2>DEF</node2>
    <node3>HIJ</node3>
    <node4>KLM</node4>
</node>
```

I don't know how to say to the code to keep the upper node, or maybe i'm wrong from the start on the way to treat it. I'm using xsl 2.0.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply write a template matching `node2`:

```
<xsl:template match="node2" mode="copy">
    <xsl:param name="value" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:next-match/>
    <node3>
        <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
    </node3>
</xsl:template>
```

then use

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$A" mode="copy">
      <xsl:with-param name="value" select="'HIJ'" tunnel="yes"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
```

and have the default template for the mode set up the identity transformation e.g. `<xsl:mode name="copy" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` in XSLT 3 or spelled out in XSLT 2 as

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="copy">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEaSuS